# N command in sed

Tags: unix, sed, aix

The 'N' command in sed works differently with Cygwin's sed(GNU sed I think) & AIX's sed.

```
$cat > input
Apple
$cat input
Apple
$sed 'N' input
$cat > input
Apple
Orange
$sed 'N' input
Apple
Orange
$
```

As seen above, the first `sed 'N' input` command printed nothing for AIX's sed as there was no new input line. However Cygwin's sed printed `Apple` for the same.
Can some unix/sed guru throw some light into this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it might be a problem with new lines in cygwin. You may try `dos2unix` in the input file before filtering through `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like AIX is behaving correctly, as per the POSIX standard (my italics):

> [2addr]**N**
>
> Append the next line of input, less its terminating < newline >, to the pattern space, using an embedded < newline > to separate the appended material from the original material. Note that the current line number changes.
>
> *If no next line of input is available, the N command verb shall branch to the end of the script and quit without starting a new cycle or copying the pattern space to standard output.*

This is from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html.

So, you've probably found a bug (or a least a non-conformance to POSIX) in GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I just found this behavior has been documented here:
http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html#s6.7.5